# Paypal within iFrame on Facebook

Tags: paypal, facebook-canvas, iframe-app

Double iframe here.  Within the Facebook Canvas iframe, we're iframing another window to starbucks.com for our egifting section.  Problem is, and what use to work, the paypal button will no longer break out of the iframes and render their page before being submitted and back into the iframes.  Example, visit https://apps.facebook.com/starbuckscard/ and select paypal as an option when you get to it.    This use to work ... any idea on why or what's broken/changed???  Any feedback much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All PayPal URL's will break out of iframes, or return an error depending on whether the browser adheres to `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` which is set for all pages (including Website Payments Standard) to `SAMEORIGIN`.

You'd want to use PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution instead, which allows itself to be embedded within an iframe.

Comment: p.s.  what's confusing though, is we've changed nothing in our code ... it simply started breaking. I wonder if FB added/modified/removed anything from within their "shell" that might have caused this ... know of anything?

Comment: PayPal recently added the X-FRAME-Options HTTP header; it wasn't strictly enforced previously

Comment: I want to do similar thing? did you find a solution? is there sandbox for paypal website pay pro and does it work well inside facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can do transactions on server side as well.
Here is full REST API docs and examples:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Comment: Any explanation or examples would be really helpful.